# Компилятор выбирает не правильный конструктор

Tags: c++, list, шаблоны-с++, конструктор

Пишу свой реализацию std::list, подсмотрел кунструтор [оригинала (line 487, 529)](http://cs.brown.edu/people/jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/stl__list_8h-source.html) и сделал также:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
    typedef T                           value_type;
    typedef size_t                      size_type;

    explicit List(size_type n, value_type const & val) : m_begin(NULL), m_end(NULL), m_size(0)
    {
        std::cout << "you" << std::endl;
    }

    template <class InputIterator>
        List(InputIterator first, InputIterator second) : m_begin(NULL), m_end(NULL), m_size(0)
    {
        std::cout << "no you" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

main.cpp :

```
int main ()
{
    ft::List<int> first (3,100);
    return 0;
}
```

Ожидаю вывод "you"
Но выводится "no you"

Почему так происходит и как исправить?

UPD:
Ожидаю что конструктор будет работать как у std::list lst(3, 100);

Comment: Подозреваю что это изза `typeof(3) == int` -> выбирается конструктор с одинаковыми типами параметров так как не нужно преобразование типов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, если исправить простые ошибки в вашем коде, чтоб он компилировался, то достаточно написать

```
List<int> first (3u,100);
```

Все просто. Вы передаете 2 значения `int`.  Для второго конструктора не требуется никаких неявных приведений, один и тот же тип `InputIterator`... а во втором - первый параметр - `unsigned`, так что требуется приведение. Так что выбран будет второй конструктор.

А когда мы дает аргументы правильных типов - дело другое, теперь приведение требуется во втором конструкторе...

Если вы хотите как контрпример привести стандартный `list`, так у него версия с итераторами проверяет, что это и в самом деле итераторы - например, в VC++:

```
template<class _Iter,
    class = enable_if_t<_Is_iterator_v<_Iter>>>
    list(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last)
```

Поэтому для двух `int`'ов выбирать - как это делается у вас - не из чего...

Comment: Но std::list<int> lst(5, 100); работает как ожидается

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что *стандартный* `list` имеет тот же интерфейс, что и ваш?... См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: То есть не существует способа повторить поведение оригинала стандартными средствами с++98 ?

Comment: @Антон В конце ответа ж написано, как повторить.

Comment: C++98 - это так давно было, уже и не помню. Глянул в Open Watcom - он у меня один такой старый валяется - так там `list` от двух итераторов еще и аллокатор должен третьим параметром передавать. Не могу сказать, это у всех так, или только у Watcom'а...

Comment: @Антон Можно самостоятельно написать `enable_if`, если ваш компилятор его не поддерживает. А чем вы компилируете, что даже не C++03, а вообще C++98?